# TagHelper for passing route values as part of a link with this format /users/edit/10

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I need to pass an ID for my resource as part of the URL. Is there any way that I can have the link formatted like this /users/edit/10 using the tag helper?

I've seen the following example on another question, but this gives me user/edit?id=10&foo=bar. Not really what I am looking for. :(

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="10" asp-route-foo="bar">Edit</a>
```

Below is the actual function that I am trying to reach:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[controller]/edit/{blogId:int}")]
public IActionResult BlogEdit(int blogId)
{

    Blog blog = _blogRepo.GetById(blogId);

    BlogEditViewModel blogEditViewModel = new BlogEditViewModel
    {
        Title = blog.Title,
        Body = blog.Body,
        Id = blog.Id
    };

    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Blog";
    return View(blogEditViewModel);
}
```

I Tried using the a tag below, but it's still generating the incorrect link.

```
<a asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="BlogEdit" asp-route-blogId="11">Edit Blog 11</a>
```

The above link generates the path below.

```
http://localhost:52409/Blog/edit?blogId=11
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share how your routes are defined?

Comment: I am using attribute routing. This is the definition for my routing: 

[Route("[controller]/edit/{blogId:int}")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, modify the tag helper attribute name from `asp-route-id` to `asp-route-blogid` and things should work.

Comment: I tried using 
`<a asp-controller="Blog" asp-action="BlogEdit" asp-route-blogId="11">Edit Blog 11</a>`
as you suggested, but it is still not generating the link in the correct format. 

`http://localhost:52409/Blog/edit?blogId=11`

Answer (score 1):

Given the complexity `Attribute-based` routes **could** have, it's quite hard to come up with a way to have a taghelper render a link like `/blog/edit/11`.

If the above link followed a *standard route*, then it becomes quite easy to reproduce as desired; but such is not the case here.

So, what to do? **Named Routes**

If you were to define your function like so:

```
HttpGet]
[Route("[controller]/edit/{blogId:int}", Name = "BlogEdit")]
public IActionResult BlogEdit(int blogId)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can define a TagHelper link as follows too:

```
<a asp-route="BlogEdit" asp-route-blogId="11">Edit Blog 11</a>
```

Which should render the following link:

```
<a href="/blog/edit/11">Edit Blog 11</a>
```